# Getting nested unread messages from within a message thread

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `message_threads` and `messages`. When returning a results set of `message_threads`, I'm performing a `JOIN` on the two tables to see whether **any** message from the sender (to the receiver) within that thread is unread.

Below is my SQL...

```
SELECT mt.id AS thread_id, m.id AS message_id,
m.is_read, m.from_type, mt.company_id
FROM message_threads AS mt
LEFT JOIN messages AS m
ON m.thread_id = mt.id;
```

...the full results set from a given query...

```
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| thread_id | message_id | is_read | from_type | company_id |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          1 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         1 |          9 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         1 |         19 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         2 |          2 | Y       | coder     |          1 |
|         2 |          3 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         2 |          6 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         2 |          8 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         3 |          4 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         6 |         13 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         6 |         14 | N       | coder     |          1 |
|         6 |         15 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         8 |         20 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         8 |         21 | N       | coder     |          1 |
|         4 |          5 | N       | company   |          2 |
|         4 |          7 | N       | company   |          2 |
|         4 |         22 | N       | coder     |          2 |
|         5 |         10 | N       | company   |          8 |
|         5 |         11 | N       | coder     |          8 |
|         5 |         12 | N       | company   |          8 |
|         7 |         16 | N       | company   |         18 |
|         7 |         17 | N       | coder     |         18 |
|         7 |         18 | N       | company   |         18 |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

...and the desired result set:

```
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
| thread_id | message_id | is_read | from_type | company_id |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
|         1 |         19 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         2 |          2 | Y       | coder     |          1 |
|         3 |          4 | N       | company   |          1 |
|         6 |         14 | N       | coder     |          1 |
|         8 |         21 | N       | coder     |          1 |
|         4 |         22 | N       | coder     |          2 |
|         5 |         11 | N       | coder     |          8 |
|         7 |         17 | N       | coder     |         18 |
+-----------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

How can I perform this query? I've tried `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`, and neither quite do what I want. I also can't do this using a `WHERE` clause to filter my data, because I need all the threads regardless of the `is_read` flag.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you decide which message_id to return from each thread group?

Comment: There's not quite enough to go on here to figure out the correct call with all the fields you want. What are your expectations for the message_id and from type columns? You're likely going to end up with some sort of group by and I suspect either a case or sub-select, but I can't really advise based on what you show here.

Comment: I'm not sure, and I think that is part and parcel with my question. The message_id ideally would be that of the most recent unread sender, otherwise any other message.

Comment: So then wouldn't it be (e.g.) thread/message 2,8 rather than 2,2 that gets returned in the result set?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Sure, though it doesn't really matter. I'm only looking for cases where `from_type = 'coder' AND is_read='N'` nested within those threads.

Comment: I think you'd at least want a consistent experience, rather than "any other message", would it not be better to return the most recently sent message if no unread message exists?

Comment: @ninesided I don't really need the message content in the thread itself (though it might be nice). Only the thread title and some other metadata associated with it (who sent the message, the subject line, etc.). +1 for thinking about UX in a MySQL question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of doing this. If your looking to see the number of unread messages from a thread you may want to join an inner query.

Example:

```
SELECT 
mt.id AS thread_id, 
mt.company_id,
CASE WHEN m_c.m_unread IS NOT NULL THEN m_c.m_unread ELSE 0 END AS unread
FROM message_threads AS mt
LEFT JOIN 
( 
  SELECT
  thread_id,
  COUNT(*) AS m_unread
  FROM messages
  WHERE
  is_read ='N'
  GROUP BY 1
)m_c
ON mt.thread_id = m_c.thread_id
```

Comment: You can avoid the case statement by using `COALESCE(m_c.m_unread, 0)`

Comment: This and @Ilion's comment were exactly what I needed.